# Why would a multimeter give an unexpected current reading?

Tags: multimeter, amperage, adapter

I assume that the multimeter should read 2A for a 2A power supply, why is it only 0.358A?

**Edit:** After watching a video on [the basics of using a multimeter](https://youtu.be/TdUK6RPdIrA), I realised that as well as short circuiting a power supply (which will break your multimeter), I was using the terminals incorrectly; the 20A fuse has indeed blown. Luckily it was a cheap multimeter, so was a relatively inexpensive lesson.

[image: Connection to multimeter]

Comment: Stop short circuiting your power supply with multimeter before something gets damaged - or you end up with a blown fuse.

Comment: Understood, no more short circuiting with multimeters for me. I tried using this multimeter to measure the current of a 1000W fan, but when I connect it in series, the fan doesn't work at all (I don't understand why; maybe because the multimeter is max 20A, so at 12V that'd only be 240W, which is about 25% of what I guess the fan's load is). My multimeter unfortunately doesn't have a current clamp (perhaps I should get a better multimeter).

Comment: Correction: I meant 100W, not 1000W. But that raises more questions; if it's a 8.7A load, that's within the 20A limit for the multimeter, so it should work (but doesn't).

Comment: If you've previously used your multimeter on that 20A range to try to measure current in the way that you were trying to measure that poor power supply, then you've almost certainly blown the 20A fuse in your multimeter - and it won't work on the 20A range again until you replace the fuse.

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense. Thanks, I’ll do that.

Comment: Update: I realised the issue; I was using the wrong terminals, so the current didn't go through the 20A fuse. That said, it's only a 2A power supply, so I'm guessing it wouldn't have blown the fuse anyway (and the power supply will shut off automatically anyway). I'm lucky that the power supply had this a safety feature. I wonder: do some AC/DC supplies not have this safety feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your meter is acting as a short across the output of the adapter, since an ammeter has a very low resistance shunt for measuring current.

It's probable that the short causes a kind of hiccup current limit, meaning the output shuts down for a period then restarts.  This may be too fast to see on your meter, so the meter is reading the average current, not the peak. (Or it could be fold-back limiting as well as others have mentioned.)

An ammeter is meant to be put in series with the load, so if you put it in series and gradually increase the load to the point of current limit you should be able to measure the max current out of the adapter.

Comment: Got it, I'll make sure to always put it in series and not short circuit. Interesting about the output shutting down, and that the meter may be reading the average current from the hiccups.

Answer (score 4):

It may be that the power supply has current fold-back. Instead of going into a regulated current mode and supplying its maximum rated current when short circuited, it supplies something less.

I'm sure it wasn't designed (like a bench supply) to be operated with such a low load resistance.

Comment: At work we've been dealing with some combinations of power supply & load put together by Other People -- if nothing else, it's educated me that wall-warts seem to come with some pretty good over current protection, at least to the extent of not burning themselves up if you short their outputs.

Answer (score 3):

**That's not how you test a power supply.** That's how you bust multimeters.

The PSU is rated at 12 V, 2 A. From Ohm's Law we can calculate that it can work with a load down to \$ R = \frac V I = \frac {12}2 = 6 \ \Omega \$.

Alternatively we can calculate the maximum power it can supply as \$ P = VI = 12 \times 2 = 24 \ \text W \$.

Short-circuiting it as you did may have put the PSU into current limit and it has, effectively, shut down.

If you can find a suitable load then connect the meter in series with the load.

Comment: I found a 1000W load (a salvaged DC fan). When I connect it to the 12V 2A adapter, the fan works very feebly (I guess because 24W isn't enough to make it do much), but unfortunately when I connect the multimeter in series, the fan doesn't work at all (I don't understand why; maybe because the multimeter is max 20A, so at 12V that'd only be 240W, which is about 25% of what I guess the fan's load is). My multimeter unfortunately doesn't have a current clamp (perhaps I should get a better multimeter).

Comment: Correction: I meant 100W, not 1000W. But that raises more questions; if it's a 8.7A load, that's within the 20A limit for the multimeter, so it should work (but doesn't).

Comment: Most DC fans are not simple motors. Instead they are brushless DC (BLDC) motors with built-in electronics to pulse the three-phase windings in the correct sequence and timing. The fan is not a good test load.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other good answers here, there is a fundamental concept that must be understood here:

(Typical) DC power supplies are intended to output a specific voltage, but they don't provide a particular current. Current is a product of voltage divided by resistance. So the circuit/load itself determines the current.

The current rating on a typical DC supply is not how many amps the supply outputs, it's how many amps it *can* output.

Comment: Ah, do you mean: the amps on the label is how many amps it can output before going into a failsafe mode/hiccup current limit/current fold-back?

Comment: @NickBolton - Essentially. Modern power supplies should have a failsafe of some sort. They don't always trip right at the limit. Cheaper supplies will drop in voltage far before they reach the stated current limit. (Not a failsafe, just a failure to supply the needed power). So you could end up with 11V at 1.5A.