# Will a 250V fuse work fine in a 1000V multimeter?

Tags: multimeter, fuses

I busted my multimeter due to improper use (see [Why would a multimeter give an unexpected current reading?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/571470/why-would-a-multimeter-give-an-unexpected-current-reading)) and so decided to change the fuse. Annoyingly I can’t seem to find a 15A 1000V 6.3mm x 32mm fuse, and the closest thing I can find is a 15A 250VAC fuse. I was going to go ahead and assume yes, since I’m only ever going to test DC voltages around 24V or below (but you never know, I may use it to test up to 230VAC in future), but I thought I’d check with the experts before happening upon another silly mistake. The multimeter is an Owon OW18E.

[image: Inside Owon OW18E]

Also, curiously, the rating on the front says 20A.

[image: External of Owon OW18E]

Also, is it likely that a 1000V 15A 6.3mm x 32mm fuse can be purchased in the UK? I've checked all the usuals in the UK (Farnell, RS, etc), but the highest rated seems to be 250V at 15A. Alternatively, I found a 600V at 10A, but so far nothing near 1000V 15A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes but **ONLY** on the condition that you don't use your multimeter above the fuse rating of 250V.  The problem is that a fuse may arc instead of blowing at a voltage higher than its rating so the protection you're counting on will not be there.

I strongly recommend that if you do this you clearly label the meter with a "250V LIMIT" warning so that you don't forget or someone else who uses the meter is aware.

Comment: yeah, put a "250V CAT II" label over the bit where is says "1000V 600V"

Answer (score 2):

It will reduce the safety of your multimeter, and may perhaps invalidate its safety ratings. A 15 A 1000V fuse is rated to blow at 15 A of current, and will withstand 1000 V across it without arcing or putting you in danger.

By reducing the fuse rating to 250 V, you now have a multimeter that won't keep you safe if it's exposed to a voltage over 250 V. It certainly will no longer be a CAT-III multimeter rated to handle 1000 V operation.

An alternative would be a fuse with a lower rated current, but a 1 kVac rating. You'll risk nuisance trips, but you won't risk your fuses failing to protect you when you need them. A [quick search](https://www.digikey.com/short/nfbw1z32) found a few fuses at lower currents and one model that is rated 15 A / 1000 V. Without knowing the dimensions of your meter's fuseholder, it's not clear whether they will match.